# ASP.NET Core MVC how to submit the form data to database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, postgresql, view

I have an asp.net project in which I need to create a table in which all the elements of the whole row are sent into the database. I am using PostgreSQL and have already created the table in the database and added the migration. I have created a form but whenever I try to open the page I get a Null Error, or , if I put the[HttpPost] which I think I should, before my program, I get a http 405 error. Can anyone tell me why?

model:

```
public class RegisteredRecord
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }


        public string webPort { get; set; }

        public string jmxPort { get; set; }


        public string Os { get; set; }


        public string cpuType { get; set; }

        public string cpuSpeed { get; set; }

        public string nrOfCpus { get; set; }

        public string nrOfCoresPerCpu { get; set; }


        public string totalNrOfCores { get; set; }


        public string ramSize { get; set; }

        public string hddSize { get; set; }

        public string ip { get; set; }

    }
```

controller:

```
 public class TableController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IEnumerable<RegisteredRecord> regs;
        private readonly IRegisteredRecordRepository _registeredRecordRepository;
        public TableController(IRegisteredRecordRepository registeredRecordRepository)
        {
            _registeredRecordRepository = registeredRecordRepository;
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Table(string Name, string name, string webPort, string jmxPort, string Os, string cpuType, string cpuSpeed, string nrOfCpus, string nrOfCoresPerCpu, string totalNrOfCores, string ramSize, string hddSize, string ip)
        {

            RegisteredRecord reg = new RegisteredRecord();
                {
                
                reg.name = HttpContext.Request.Form["txtname"].ToString();
                reg.webPort = HttpContext.Request.Form["txtwebport"].ToString();
                reg.jmxPort = HttpContext.Request.Form["txtjmxport"].ToString();
                reg.Os = HttpContext.Request.Form["txtos"].ToString();
                reg.cpuType = HttpContext.Request.Form["txtcputype"].ToString();
                reg.cpuSpeed = HttpContext.Request.Form["txtspeed"].ToString();
                reg.nrOfCpus = HttpContext.Request.Form["txtnrofcpus"].ToString();
                reg.nrOfCoresPerCpu = HttpContext.Request.Form["txtnrofcorespercpu"].ToString();
                reg.totalNrOfCores = HttpContext.Request.Form["txttotalnrofcores"].ToString();
                reg.ramSize = HttpContext.Request.Form["txtramsize"].ToString();
                reg.hddSize = HttpContext.Request.Form["txthddsize"].ToString();
                reg.ip = HttpContext.Request.Form["txtip"].ToString();
                _registeredRecordRepository.AddExcelList(reg);

            };
                
            

            _registeredRecordRepository.GetExcelList();

            return View(reg);

        }
    }
```

helper class for display:

````
public static List<RegisteredRecord> reg = new List<RegisteredRecord>();```

view:
````

@model IEnumerable<Proiect2PracticaClona.Models.RegisteredRecord>

```
<form asp-controller="Table" asp-action="Table">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td><input name="txtname" type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>WebPort:</td>
            <td><input name="txtwebport" type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>JmxPort:</td>
            <td><input name="txtjmxport" type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Os:</td>
            <td><input name="txtos" type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>CpuType:</td>
            <td><input name="txtcputype" type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>CpuSpeed:</td>
            <td><input name="txtcpuspeed" type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>NrOfCpus:</td>
            <td><input name="txtnrofcpus" type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>NrOfCoresPerCpu:</td>
            <td><input name="txtnrofcorespercpu" type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>TotalNrOfCores:</td>
            <td><input name="txttotalnrofcores" type="text" /></td>
        <tr>
            <td>RamSize:</td>
            <td><input name="txtramsize" type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>HddSize:</td>
            <td><input name="txthddsize" type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ip:</td>
            <td><input name="txtip" type="text" value="ip" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: I think you need two methods in your controller - one with `[HttpGet]` which returns a view containing a form to enter the details of the entity to add to the database, and one with `[HttpPost]` which handles submission of the form, adds the entity to the database, and returns whatever view you want to show to the user next (display the details of the record which has just been created?). The most likely reason for the 405 HTTP status is that the initial attempt to display the form is making a `GET` request to your controller and the controller only has a method to handle `POST` requests.

Comment: I suspect the exception you're getting when the controller method doesn't have `[HttpPost]` is because the initial load of the page (before the user has entered any data) is looking for data contained in a form submission, and the user hasn't actually submitted a form yet. If you could add the details of the exception (Message and StackTrace properties) to your question then that would help to confirm this.